# populating a datatable using linq to sql and stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

```
 public void populatetransaction()
    {
        TRANASACTIONHISTRORYDataContext th = new TRANASACTIONHISTRORYDataContext();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var query = from dr
                 in th.TRANSACTIONSP((System.Nullable<long>)Convert.ToInt32(hidreference.Value))
                    select dr;
        dt = (DataTable)query;



    }
```

here is my code in that `th.TRANSACTIONSP((System.Nullable<long>)Convert.ToInt32(hidreference.Value))`
is the procedure calling how can i do that

Comment: is it asp.net web forms project ?

Comment: In the name of all that's Holy! Why you might need a DataTable if there is an ORM?

Comment: because  i have one datatable already  and need to merge the result with it

Comment: Use `Concat` method on `DbSet`. Forget `DataTable`.

Comment: can you check my answer i need to get a result like this is there any other method for the same @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 0):

```
public void populatetransaction()
    {
        TRANASACTIONHISTRORYDataContext th = new TRANASACTIONHISTRORYDataContext();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var query= th.TRANSACTIONSP((System.Nullable<long>)Convert.ToInt32(hidreference.Value));
        DataColumn dc1 = dt.Columns.Add("BTC", typeof(string));
        dc1.AllowDBNull = true;
        DataColumn dc2 = dt.Columns.Add("TRANSACTIONDATE", typeof(DateTime));
        dc2.AllowDBNull = true;
        DataColumn dc3 = dt.Columns.Add("TRANSACTIONSTATUS", typeof(string));
        DataRow dw ;
        dc3.AllowDBNull = true;

        foreach (var c in query)
        {
            dw=dt.NewRow();
            dw["BTC"] = c.BTC;
            dw["TRANSACTIONDATE"] = c.TRANSACTIONDATE;
            dw["TRANSACTIONSTATUS"] = c.TRANSACTIONSTATUS;
            dt.Rows.Add(dw);
        }
       }
```

This was what I want